# How can I explode at "," in php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a `javascript` array and i code it with `JSON.stringify()` and I subjoin it into the `url`. I decode it in a `php`with a `$_GET`. And afert decode i got  string like this:

```
["a","\nb","\nc","\nd"]
```

Now i should explode it and get a php array with values a,b,c.

So, I should do sg like this:
$array=explode("","\n",$values);
To sum up I should explode a string at : `","\n`charatrer chain or if someone got a better solution, i will appriciate it.

Comment: ... explode(',', $string);

Comment: use explode() function

Comment: it's confusing..Do you want to convert ["a","\nb","\nc","\nd"] to ['a', 'b', 'c'] ??

Comment: Add a fully working example. Why are there '\n' characters in the array in the first place?

Comment: I want to convert  ["a","\nb","\nc","\nd"] to $values[0]=a, $values[1]=b; $values[2]=c;

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)? It's not clear what you actually got. A JSON string or a PHP array?

Comment: Have a javascipt array and i want to convert it into php. I read it that i have to use json.

Comment: Please add your javascript code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $array=$_GET['values'];
//its equals:["a","\nb","\nc","\nd"]
    $values=explode('["', $array);
    $values=explode('"]', $values[1]);
    $values=explode('","\n', $values[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$arr =  ["a","\nb","\nc","\nd"] ;

foreach($arr as $str) {
    $str = str_replace('\n', '', $str);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Hi mishanon; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I mean looks like this：

```
$str = str_replace('[', '', $str);
$str = str_replace(']', '', $str);
$arr = explode(',', $str);
var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have JSON string representing an array use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then clean the newlines from array elements.

```
$array = json_decode($_GET['values'], true);
foreach ($array as $k=>$v)
    $array[$k] = trim($v);
```

Or on the JavaScript side, send the data without the newlines and just use `json_decode()`.